# React Navigation v6 - Deep Linking with nested navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I'm attempting to add login via a magic link. I have setup the deep linking config for iOS and Android and the app opens however I'm struggling to get it to open the appropriate screen. The screen I'm trying to open is nested like so:

```
Root (Stack Navigator)
  └── Tabs (Bottom Tab Navigator)
        ├── ProfileTab (Stack Navigator)
        │     └── MagicLinkSent (Screen)
        └── Other Tabs...
```

I currently have my config setup like so:

```
export const linking = {
  prefixes: ['appname://'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Tabs: {
        initialRouteName: 'ProfileTab',
        screens: {
          ProfileTab: {
            initialRouteName: 'MagicLinkSent',
            screens: {
              MagicLinkSent: 'auth/v1/magic',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      NotFound: '*',
    },
  },
};
```

However I'm getting this error `The navigation state parsed from the URL contains routes not present in the root navigator. This usually means that the linking configuration doesn't match the navigation structure.`

I've followed the link to the docs but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.